# What does the notation P(X = 5|X ≥ 3) mean in terms of random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics

For reference, here is the full question:

> Let X is a Geometric random variable with parameter p. You answers for the
>   following questions with be a function of p. What is the value of P(X = 5|X ≥ 3)

I don't understand what that notation means. Is it asking for the value of P(X = 5) given that

X >= 3?

Comment: Precisely. This is called conditional probability (i.e. the probability of a given event subject to some condition)

Comment: Have you come across conditional probability (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) concept?

Comment: Yes, I have come across conditional probability. This makes sense. 

However, now I am confused as to how to find the intersection of P(X=5) and P(X >= 3)

@Brenton

Comment: @HumanCyborgRelations Well notice that when X=5, then X >= 3, so their intersection is just X=5

Answer (score 3):

By definition,
$$
P(X = 5 \mid X \geq 3) = \frac{P(X = 5 \land X \geq 3)}{P(X \geq 3)} = \frac{P(X = 5)}{P(X \geq 3)}.
$$
Generally, $P(A | B) = P(A \cap B)/P(B)$, for events $A,B$ with $P(B) > 0$.